# О склонении. Три способа: реализованные или реализованных?

Tags: склонение

Из Википедии, статья "Винилхлорид":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> На 2010 год существуют три основных способа получения винилхлорида, **реализованные** в промышленных масштабах.

Мне кажется, тут должно быть "реализованных". Я прав, или "реализованные" тоже подходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Википедии формально согласовано верно. Но лучше будет изменить на:

> На 2010 год существу**е**т три основных способа получения винилхлорида, реализованны**х** в промышленных масштабах.

То есть с *реализованных* должно быть существу**е**т в единственном числе.

Answer (score 3):

> реализованные? реализованных?

По-моему, ни то ни другое. Лучше так:

***На 2010 год существуют три основных способа получения винилхлорида в промышленных масштабах.***

Или так:

***На 2010 год реализованы три основных способа получения винилхлорида в промышленных масштабах.***

Comment: Нет слова — нет проблемы.

Comment: Простите, Слава, за лишнюю запятую! Убедился, что она не нужна.